# How to resolve error in pom.xml - android eclipse application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I have error in pom.xml file. I don't understand what means xml elements in this file. I'm using eclipse's maven plugin version 1.4.0. 
Is there problem in pom.xml elements, versions of plugins, platforms...  The code in pom.xml file is:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>at.axtesys</groupId>
    <artifactId>soljoy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>soljoy</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>3.9.0-rc.1</android.plugin.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus</id>
        <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.loopj.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tony19</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-android-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>19</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error is:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:pom:2.10 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider- api:pom:2.10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

Is problem in some configuration parametar or versions of maven plugin in pom.xml file and my eclipse version of plugin?

Answer (score 3):

The error contains the Maven coordinates `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider- api:pom:2.10` - notice the space between `provider-` and `api`? Might this be the culprit?

If this is not the issue (and just a copy'n'paste problem) I'd check if the artifact can be fetched if you force its re-fetch via the `-U` Maven option.

Comment: What about space between provider and api? (I'm beginner with xml and android programing :) ) What can I do for fixing problem if this space problem?

Comment: Well, there must be no spaces in between a Maven coordinate, so you might have accidentally added this somewhere. But again, I think it might be worthwhile to clear the Maven cache or disable it's usage via `-U`, as I think you might just experience a temporary issue.